# How can I write a method that extracts :path and file name from the file instance, to use in a scanner method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to extract the path and file name from an uploaded file so I can run scanner on them. Thanks!

The ideas I had were:

`scanner = Bundler::Audit::Scanner.new(root=:path,gemfile_lock=file_file_name)`

`scanner = Bundler::Audit::Scanner.new(File.dirname,File.file_file_name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the guide for [uploading files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files)? The `params` will return a `StringIO` or `File` object that provides the upload as a `Tempfile`. Using a gem like `Paperclip` makes the process of uploading and scanning much simpler, so would definitely recommend trying it out.

Also, the `File` methods you called are **class** methods, so you need to pass an instance to them.

Assuming that you want to scan the Tempfile, then save or discard it, you could do something like this in your controller:

```
def upload_file
  uploaded_io = params[:uploaded_file]
  tempfile = uploaded_io.tempfile
  path = tempfile.path

  # If you need to separate the dir and filename
  dir = File.dirname(path)
  filename = File.basename(path)
  scanner = Bundler::Audit::Scanner.new(dir, filename)
end
```